# Can you run a mediation analysis using beta regression

Tags: mediation, beta-regression

When running a beta regression in R I am interested in seeing if there are any potential mediators to my primary outcome. My primary outcome is bounded between 0 and 1 and I therefore am unsure I can use an orthodox mediation analysis process. **Is it possible to run a mediation analysis on data bounded between 0 and 1** and if so does anyone have any advice as to how this would be done using R studio?

Comment: I see no reason you could not follow the same plan as you would for "regular" regression, only using beta.  There are various methods for doing a mediation analysis, and any of them should work just as well with beta.    Is there a reason you think it would not?

Comment: @PeterFlom thanks so much. My only reasons for uncertainty are that I can find no details online outlining the process specifically for betaregression and the "betareg" R package provides no instruction for mediation analyses. My uncertainty does not come from seeing a specific flaw in the theory of doing a mediation analysis with beta but with the lack of information available about the process making me question its validity. There may also be something to be said for the unorthodox nature of a beta distribution?

Comment: Beta regression is a pretty uncommon method, so, I'm not surprised that nothing has been written on doing mediation with it. But the logic of mediation analysis seems to be exactly the same.